# Checking length in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Having this code:

```
if ($('.course-chkbox:checked').length === 0) {
alert('no course is selected');
}
```

Is this the correct way to check for length??? I cant get it working in some browser. Therefore I ask.

**UPDATE**

I figured out it wasn't the actual checking of number of checkbox checkboxes that was the issue, but the issue lays in how many checkboxes actually are checked.

Why doesn't this down below code work in IE 8? The length always get to 0!

```
$(document).on('click', 'label', function(e) { 
var tClicked = $(this);                            
var checkbox = $('#' + $(this).attr('for'));            

if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {  
    tClicked.removeClass('checkbox-checked');      
    checkbox.checked = false;
} else {
    tClicked.addClass('checkbox-checked');            
    checkbox.checked = true;
}
```

});

The checkbox-checked class adds an background-image to a label.

The html looks something like this:

```
<input class="course-chkbox" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="course_<id>"</label>
```

Comment: what is some browser?

Comment: Yes, the correct way of checking length is using `length`. If it doesn't work, you should provide full context code.

Comment: you need to post your complete code.

Comment: This works in all browsers.  What "can't you get working" in which browser(s)?  What's the problem?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld: What about `===`?

Comment: This is a long shot, but what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @Polaris878 - I figured out now that it has nothing to do with that. IE8 does not care about checkboxes that are set to display:none. Is there a way to "hide" them (I don't care where they are). But to answer your question: I'm using v1.11.0. Its not possible to use display:none or visibility:hidden (then ie8 doesnt trigger the checkboxes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length check you have works in every browser, as jQuery is returning an array-like object which has a length property.

Comment: jQuery is actually returning a jQuery object, not an array.  It just so happens that the object it returns has a `length` property.  The object it returns is "array-like".

Comment: You are right, not sure how I missed that :)

Comment: "array like object" could be confused with "array which is like an object". Better use "array-like object"

Comment: Thanks for answer. But then I figured out this wasn't my actual issue. Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

Because I was very unclear in my original question. **Forgive me for that!** I will provide an answer here in case somone happens to stumble upon this issue:

In case someone wants to style checkboxes. Please take in consideration that IE8 and below does not have support for "triggering" checkbox-events when set to `display:none` or `visiblity:hidden;`

I solved the issue by putting this in header-file: (another why to hide it)

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
#adduser .course-chkbox {
display:inline-block !important;
border: 0;
clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
height: 1px;
margin: -1px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 1px;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```